# (SOLVED) How can I take away 10 from a slider value in C# for unity2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider

I tried taking away 10 from the slider's value, but upon testing, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Code:

```cs
public static void NoteMiss()
{
    //takeAway = (float)bar.value - 10;
    bar = GameObject.Find("HealthBar").GetComponent<Slider>();
    //FCTxt.text = "";
    print("Note Miss!");
    Misses = Misses + 1;
    bar.value -= 10; // line to take away
    //FC = false;
}
```

All values used there are set to static.

edit:
I found the issue, the function NoteMiss wasn't getting called anywhere because of a comment in another script that I didn't remember was there.
Sorry for my poor explanation!

Comment: What’s the min/max values on your slider?

Comment: Well how did you add values to the slider in the first place?

Comment: Well without further information: Just like this. What exactly does `it doesn't work` mean?